# org.springframework.orm.jpa.localcontainer jang.lang.classNotFoundException

Tags: spring, jsf

i am using maven and spring with JSF2 but while deploying the application i got the error jang.lang.classNotFoundException org.springframework.orm.jpa.localcontainer .

My question this error about the dependencies in the pom.xml or in the configuration web.xml and applicationContext.xml ?

thanks in advance .

this is applicationContext.xml

```
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties"/>
         <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/${jpa.dsatasource}"/>
    <!-- Enable Spring Annotation Configuration -->
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <!-- Scan for all of Spring components such as Spring Service -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.sfuture.gidee"/>

    <context:load-time-weaver/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainer"
            p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
         <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
                    p:databasePlatform="${jpa.databasePlatform}" p:showSql="${jpa.showSql}"/>
        </property>

        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml"/>

    </bean>

  <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
            p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

this is web.xml

```
   <context-param>

        <param-name>primefaces.CLIENT_SIDE_VALIDATION</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
     <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
     <context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>sunny</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener> 

and this is faces-config.xml


  <application>
     <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application >
```

Comment: No. This class just doesn't exist: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/package-summary.html. Re-read the documentation.

Comment: please this is my first application using spring . i add the dependency of spring-orm should i add something alse to make this class exist ?

Comment: No. You need to read the documentation to know which correct type you must use instead of LocalContainer, which does not exist. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#orm-jpa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

`class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainer"`

into

```
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
```

because you are refering a class which is not-exists.

> **[LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html):**
>
> FactoryBean that creates a JPA
> EntityManagerFactory according to JPA's standard container bootstrap
> contract.